# Difference between these 2 padding/margin scenarious

Tags: html, css

What is the difference between using padding-left and margin-left in the following example?

http://jsfiddle.net/bt49e/1/

The left div is positioned absolutely, while the right div is either positioned with padding-left / margin-left. Can they be used interchangeably here? And are there any implications if picking one or the other?

Comment: One of the differences: they will have different computed widths - see http://jsfiddle.net/bt49e/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary difference will be the computed width, as suggested by bfavaretto.  Another difference will be the location of the border, if you were to choose to add one.  Take a look at [this update to your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bt49e/3/) to see what I mean.

You might also notice a difference in the default placement of any background image/gradient that you apply, since `margin` is added to the outside and `padding` is added to the inside of the box.